# Datapump Import Fails With ORA-39006, ORA-39213: “Metadata processing is not available”

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I am trying to import multiple dmp files using impdp command i got this error DataPump import (impdp) reports the errors:

```
Connected to: Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production

With the Partitioning, OLAP and Data Mining options

ORA-39006: internal error

ORA-39213: Metadata processing is not available
```

Attempting to correct the error ORA-39213 via

dbms_metadata_util.load_stylesheets also reports errors similar to:

```
SQL> exec dbms_metadata_util.load_stylesheets;

BEGIN dbms_metadata_util.load_stylesheets; END;

* ERROR at line 1: ORA-22288: file or LOB operation FILEEXISTs failed

Permission denied

ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_METADATA_UTIL", line 1807

ORA-06512: at line 1
```

Comment: I have exactly this situation, but anybody answered this question... Any help out there?

Answer (score 1):

login from sys and run below query worked for me oracle 11.2

```
exec dbms_metadata_util.load_stylesheets;
```